# When using Robot#mousePress my program halts

Tags: java, awtrobot

As you might have read from the title when I call Robot#mousePress my program halts, my code is as follows:

```java
if(read == 2) {
    System.out.println("Click down");
    robot.mousePress(is.read());
}
else if(read == 3) {
    System.out.println("Click up");
    robot.mouseRelease(is.read());
}
```

Where:

- "read" is the packet ID
- "is" is the socket input stream (Server side)

Now whenever I send data from the client to the server (PacketID, MouseButton), the server reads both the PacketID and MouseButton correctly and without halting (tested with printing), however when I try to add Robot#mousePress/Robot#mouseRelease it stops working, the entire code is inside a Runnable schduled using a ScheduledExecutorService that runs every millisecond.

Example code:

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        AtomicBoolean bool = new AtomicBoolean();
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            System.out.println("hey");
            if (!bool.get()) {
                bool.set(true);
                robot.mousePress(1);
            }
        }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

}
```

#### EDIT:

Instead of passing the direct number to the Robot method, put the number trough InputEvent.getMaskForButton(number)

Thanks to everyone that helped me :D

Comment: Please post a complete example which we can run, which illustrates the problem.

Comment: That's not runnable by itself. If the socket code is working, can you reduce it to a simpler example which still hangs?

Comment: Okay added client code

Comment: That’s not what I meant: reduce your example to a complete runnable class. Take out the client/server aspect and just include what’s causing the problem

Comment: If that’s impossible, explain why and at least include a thread dump when your application is stuck

Comment: @tgdavies I added it, however realize that the example code does indeed work, in my particular context it does not

Comment: OK, that's a good start. Make it more like your context until it stops working...

Comment: @tgdavies Done, I edited the example to have the same issue as my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `mousePress` an illegal argument, so it is throwing an exception. The exception won't get propagated out of the thread it's thrown in, so you will only see it if you call `get()` on the `ScheduledFuture` that `scheduleAtFixedRate` returns.

The exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid combination of button flags
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:195)
    at Test.main(Test.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid combination of button flags
    at Test.lambda$main$0(Test.java:22)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:654)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset$$$capture(FutureTask.java:336)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1521)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid combination of button flags
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Robot.checkButtonsArgument(Robot.java:316)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Robot.mousePress(Robot.java:252)
    at Test.lambda$main$0(Test.java:18)
```

Comment: Thank you, I have not used the Robot class for button presses so I was confused! I will mark this as accepted.